# SQL - How to check if users are in the same hierarchy?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data

I want to find out if users are directly in a parent child relation.

Given my user table schema

```
User_id | Parent_ID | Name
```

For example, I have a list of user_id's and I want to know if they are all in the same hierarchical tree.

I have tried using CTE recursive.

Sample data

```
User_id | Parent_ID | Name
1       |           |   A
2       |     1     |   B
3       |     2     |   C
4       |     3     |   D
5       |     2     |   E
6       |           |   F
7       |     6     |   G
```

user_id   varchar(100)

parent_id varchar(100)

Desired result: Input [2,3,4] => Same Team

Input [2,3,7] => Not same team

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help out. A recursive CTE is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the top-level parents' `parent_id` as the hierarchy identifier:

```
with recursive hierarchies as (
  select user_id, user_id as hierarchy_id
    from ttable
   where parent_id is null
  union all
  select c.user_id, p.hierarchy_id
    from hierarchies p
         join ttable c on c.parent_id = p.user_id
)
select * from hierarchies;
```

With that mapping of each `user_id` to a single `hierarchy_id`, you can join to your list of users.

**EDIT BEGINS**

Since you added sample data and example results that do not match your original question, here is an example of how any minimally competent programmer could slightly tweak the above to match the newly added contradictory examples:

```
with recursive subhierarchies as (
  select user_id, array[user_id] as path
    from ttable
   where parent_id is null
  union all
  select c.user_id, p.path||c.user_id as path
    from subhierarchies p
         join ttable c on c.parent_id = p.user_id
)
select d.user_ids, count(s.path) > 0 as same_team
  from (values (array[2, 3, 4]), (array[2, 3, 6])) as d(user_ids)
       left join subhierarchies s
         on s.path @> d.user_ids
 group by d.user_ids
;
```

Comment: After running the above query, all my users are mapped to a single hierarchy_id. Not sure how this helps in my case.

Comment: For the data posted all users **are** in a single hierarchy. Each traverses back to user_id 1. You need to either have another root node (parent_id is null) or explain how [2,3,4] are the same team but [2,3,6] are not. You need to more clearly define what defines a team.

Comment: @AkshayKumar  It does not help in your case because you did not adequately describe the problem in your original post.  I added a solution to my answer.

Comment: Kindly excuse my ignorance as I am new to SO and psql Thank you for you answer @Mike. It works for me with little tweaks.